# Rails Installing debugger (1.5.0) throws error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler

I'm trying to execute 'bundle install' for a Rails project.
but I got struck on

```
Installing debugger (1.5.0)
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension
.

        c:/jruby-1.7.4/bin/jruby.exe extconf.rb
NotImplementedError: C extension support is not enabled. Pass -Xcext.enabled=tru
e to JRuby or set JRUBY_OPTS or modify .jrubyrc to enable.

   (root) at c:/jruby-1.7.4/lib/ruby/shared/mkmf.rb:8
  require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1054
   (root) at c:/jruby-1.7.4/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/custom_require.rb:1
   (root) at extconf.rb:15


Gem files will remain installed in c:/jruby-1.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/debu
gger-1.5.0 for inspection.
Results logged to c:/jruby-1.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/debugger-1.5.0/ext/ru
by_debug/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing debugger (1.5.0), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install debugger -v '1.5.0'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Then I tried

```
$ gem install debugger -v '1.5.0'
WARNING:  RubyGems 1.2+ index not found for:


RubyGems will revert to legacy indexes degrading performance.
Updating metadata for 1 gems from http://rubygems.org/
.
complete
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
    Access to the path 'c:\Program Files\IronRuby 1.1\Lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\source
_cache' is denied.
```

All gems are properly installed but gem installation get stopped for  gem debugger (1.5.0)

My gem env is :

```
$ gem env
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.3.7
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.2 (2010-08-18 patchlevel 0) [i386-mswin32]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: c:/Program Files/IronRuby 1.1/Lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: "c:/Program Files/IronRuby 1.1/bin/ir.exe"
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: c:/Program Files/IronRuby 1.1/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - universal-dotnet-4.0
  - GEM PATHS:
     - c:/Program Files/IronRuby 1.1/Lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
     - c:/Users/swapnil/.gem/ironruby/1.9.1
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This could happen if you are using RVM and not properly sourced.

Answer (score 0):

```
NotImplementedError: C extension support is not enabled. Pass -Xcext.enabled=true to JRuby or set JRUBY_OPTS or modify .jrubyrc to enable.
```

That seems to be your issue, so just enable JRuby's C extension support and see if that works!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `JRuby` or `IronRuby`? `debugger` doesn't work with `JRuby` (see [here](https://github.com/cldwalker/debugger/issues/46)), but I've never tried it with `IronRuby`.

Answer (score 0):

The debugger gem is intended to be used only with CRuby (MRI). If you're using a different Ruby implementation, you'll need to use a debugger native to that platform.

[This blog post](http://collectiveidea.com/blog/archives/2011/06/23/prepping-your-gemfile-for-rubinius/) by Chris Gaffney explains how you can conditionally include different debugging gems based on the Ruby platform.

Comment: Are you sure about that? I would say `debugger` works in Windows platforms as well.

Comment: It works on Windows if you're using MRI. What I mean by "platform" in my answer is the type of Ruby interpreter, not the OS. JRuby and IronRuby use a completely different runtime environment (JVM and CLR) so they require a different debugger.

Comment: I meant the ruby interpreter as well. Using the `bundler`'s `:platform` terminology mentioned in your link, I would say at least `mri_19` and `mingw_19` are supported by `debugger`, and there's [an open issue](https://github.com/cldwalker/debugger/issues/46) to bring `jruby` support. But yes, it looks none of `JRuby` or `IronRuby` work with `debugger` right now.

Answer (score 0):

This could happen if you are using RVM and not properly sourced.

```
user$ source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
```

and make sure the following command returns "rvm is a function"

```
user$ type rvm | head -n 1
rvm is a function
```